# How do I convert list of numbers/strings into date format using Scheme?

Tags: scheme

If I am I given a list with 3 elements inside of it like (("October" 1 2017) ("October" 31 1990) ("June" 5 2003)). How do I return a list containing those dates as a string ie ("10/1/2017" "10/31/1990" "6/5/2003"). Right now I can only return the 1st date in the format. I want be able to use the "map" function but I am unsure how to use it in my code.

```
(define changeDate
    (lambda (date)
            (cond

                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "January" ) (list 1 (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "February" ) (list 2 (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "March" ) (list 3  (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "April" ) (list 4  (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "May" ) (list 5  (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "June" ) (list 6  (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "July" ) (list 7  (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "August" ) (list 8  (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "September" ) (list 9  (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "October" ) (list 10  (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "November" ) (list 11  (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )
                    ( (equal? (car(car date)) "December" ) (list 12  (car(cdr(car date))) (car(cdr(cdr(car date ))))) )



            )
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change all the `(car date)` forms in `changeDate` to `date` -- this will convert the function `changeDate` to one that operates on date lists of the form `("October" 1 2017)` rather than one that operates on lists of those forms
2. Now `(map changeDate '(("October" 1 2017) ("October" 31 1990) ("June" 5 2003)))` should work